# Runtime: goroutine blocks forever

Tags: go, goroutine

I have this bit of Golang code here

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    burstyLimiter := make(chan time.Time, 3)
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        burstyLimiter <- time.Now()
    }

    go func() {
        for t := range time.Tick(200 * time.Millisecond) {
            burstyLimiter <- t
        }
    }()

    burstyRequests := make(chan int, 5)
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        burstyRequests <- i
    }
    for r := range burstyRequests {
        fmt.Println("received request", r, time.Now())
    }
}
```

When I run this, it blocks forever as shown here
[image]

Then I have another slightly modified version here

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    burstyRequests := make(chan int, 5)
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        burstyRequests <- i
    }
    for r := range burstyRequests {
        fmt.Println("received request", r, time.Now())
    }
}
```

this version runs into a deadlock as expected as seen here
[image]

For the one which blocks forever, my assumption is due to the behavior of time.Tick which possibly results in a leak and the range over a channel which blocks as long as there’s a possibility of a write into the channel.

I would like to get help with clarity as to whether or not my understanding of this situation is correct.​​

Comment: They both block because you never close the channel, so the range loops never exit. (see [Range and Close](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/4) in the Tour of Go)

Comment: Please include your code *in the question*. When those external links expire the question becomes much less useful to future readers.

Comment: @JimB thank you for the answer and reference...however, I've updated my question with screenshots of the results I get when I run each code version. They both don't block forever.

Comment: @larsks Thank you. I've updated my question with the code snippets and screenshots as necessary.

Comment: @opensaucerer, they both block in exactly the same way, waiting for the `range` loop to complete. The only reason one process exits is because it's a simple deadlock which triggers the runtime to crash. If the runtime didn't didn't or couldn't detect that deadlock, it would block forever just like the other example, even if the blocking logic had no changes.

Comment: @opensaucerer, we look forward to helping you learn Go, but please don't paste screenshots of text.  Copy the text iteself and paste it, as text, into the question.

Comment: @JimB I very much appreciate your response. My own understanding of range is exactly as you've explained which is that it waits forever till a channel closes or can likely run into a deadlock if the runtime detects that there's no future possibility of a write into such channel.
Which makes me believe in my case above that the issue is due to the behvavior of `time.Tick` because if I were to use `time.After` or use an infinite loop instead, the deadlock occurs as I would expect.

Which is why my main question was just to gain clarity on this special case. Thank you very much.

Comment: Got it @erik258 My sincerest apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary issue is that you've setup a for-loop designed to pull data out of a channel, so long as it's open, without ever closing that channel. In the former case, the code blocks forever, likely because it's waiting on data to be pulled from `burstyLimiter`, which is write-deadlocked. In the latter case, the deadlock is simple enough for Go to detect it and it panics for you. To fix this, you need to do two things:

1. Ensure that the channel is closed
2. Ensure that the loop has a way to exit

Here's some code that should help you accomplish both of these:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    burstyRequests := make(chan int, 5)
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        burstyRequests <- i
    }

    defer close(burstyRequests)
loop:
    for {
        select {
            case r := <-burstyRequests:
                fmt.Println("received request", r, time.Now())
            default:
                break loop
        }
    }
}
```

This code works by first ensuring that `burstyLimiter` is closed when the function returns and then entering a loop wherein it attempts to receive from `burstyLimiter` until no more data can be received. This is the most basic way to do what you want.

If you have a more complex use-case, you could include another channel called `quit` that you send to when you want to stop receiving and then check if you receive on that or wait for data otherwise. Or you could add a timer. But, no matter what you do, you need a way to ensure that your program knows when it is done with its work and can shut down.

Comment: Thank you very much @woody1193 
Actually, I'm aware of selecting over channel and to be frank, my question isn't really a real problem, it's just an issue I encountered during an experiment and thought to see if my understanding of the situation is correct or not. 
I discussed on it more in this comment I made above
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76048956/runtime-goroutine-blocks-forever?noredirect=1#comment134140564_76048956